# How to debug Javascript process and animation?

Tags: javascript, debugging, css, firebug

There are lots of tools for debugging `JavaScript` codes (like FireBug, Chrome console), but is there a tool for debugging a process. This probably need to monitor the resource (e.g. CPU) usage to find the bottleneck in the process.

I create Javascript animations for moving an element (in a simpler case opening/closing menu), but the movement is now smooth. Different factors can cause overload, e.g. heavy CSS3 gradients. But how to detect the rate-limiting process?

*This is indeed the problem of most of websites. When opening a webpage, overload of javascript processes kills the page load. Most of animations/menu actions are broken.*

When a `JavaScript` animation is not running smooth, how do you debug the problem?

OR a more general question, how to monitor the resource usage of running JS process to make a webpage lighter (an faster load on computers with limited resources)?

Comment: *When a JavaScript animation is not running smooth, how do you debug the problem?* **Debug?** You likely mean one of these: troubleshoot, mitigate, analyse...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the timeline->frames in Chrome. Paul Irish has a lot of great talks about this, here is one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vp524yo0p44

Also when doing animation do not use setTimeout/setInterval, the precision is not good enough. Instead use requestAnimationFrame. More information about requestAnimationFrame can be found here. http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Edit: This talk by Paul is also really interesting regarding speed and debugging speed in the browser: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MllBwuHbWMY, and here is a quite recent discussing 2D transforms vs absolute positioning: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZelrwd_iRs

Answer (score 1):

### Different machines => different performance => different bottlenecks

If animation isn't running smoothly I try to lower on graphics or animation itself. Who says that users are using as powerful machines as you do? So they may hit the issue sooner than you.

But I'd still suggest [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) as it can individually show load of a particular processes. In general it's a more insightful tool compared to default Task Manager provided by Windows.